# Not all objects transferring from one list to another in beginner grid-based game

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, oop, pygame

This has been driving me nuts.

I'm developing a grid-based movement engine for a game. Character instances move around using the "move" function, which reduces their internal moves_left variable by 1 every time.

```
def move(self, direction):      #how characters move around
        if self.collision_check(direction) == True:
            print("Collision")
            return
        if self.moves_left == 0:
            print("No more moves left")
            Map.update()
            return

        elif direction == "UP":                    
                self.internal_row -= 1            
        elif direction == "LEFT":
                self.internal_column -= 1
        elif direction == "RIGHT":
                self.internal_column += 1
        elif direction == "DOWN":
                self.internal_row += 1

        self.moves_left = self.moves_left -1 
        Map.update()
```

When this variable reaches 0, they are supposed to stop moving and be transferred from the "can move" list of characters to the "no moves" list of characters. This check is in the Map.update() function.

```
for characterobject in range(0, len(Map.no_moves)-1):    #This moves any characters with moves to the can move list 
    if len(Map.no_moves) > 0:
        if Map.no_moves[characterobject].moves_left > 0:
            print("character moved from no moves to moves")
            Map.can_move.append(Map.no_moves[characterobject])
            Map.no_moves.remove(Map.no_moves[characterobject])

for characterobject in range(0, len(Map.can_move)-1):
    if len(Map.can_move) == 0:
        break
    elif Map.can_move[characterobject].moves_left == 0:     #This moves any characters with 0 moves from the can't move list to the can move list
        print("character moved from moves to no moves")
        Map.no_moves.append(Map.can_move[characterobject])
        Map.can_move.remove(Map.can_move[characterobject])
```

The problem that I'm having is that the check is not being made. When a moving character reaches moves_left = 0, the move function prints "no moves left" and Map.update() is called, but the character object stays in the list and is not transferred to the no_moves list.

Here is the full code:

```
import random 
import pygame 
import math 

pygame.init()                                 
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()                   
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode([650, 650])  
DONE = False                                  
MAPSIZE = 50    #how many tiles


TILEWIDTH  = 10     #pixel size of tile                               
TILEHEIGHT = 10
TILEMARGIN = 2

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)                             
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BROWN = (123, 123, 0)
MOVECOLOR = (150, 250, 150)

ITEMS = ["Sword", "Helmet", "Shield", "Coin"]   #just a test

KeyLookup = {
    pygame.K_LEFT: "LEFT",
    pygame.K_RIGHT: "RIGHT",
    pygame.K_DOWN: "DOWN",
    pygame.K_UP: "UP"
}


class MapTile(object):                       #The main class for stationary things that inhabit the grid ... grass, trees, rocks and stuff.
    def __init__(self, name, internal_column, internal_row):
        self.name = name
        self.internal_column = internal_column
        self.internal_row = internal_row


class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight


class Character(object):                    #can_move can move around and do cool stuff
    def __init__(self, name, HP, internal_column, internal_row):
        self.name = name
        self.HP = HP
        self.internal_column = internal_column
        self.internal_row = internal_row

    inventory = []
    moves_left = 25

    def move(self, direction):      #how characters move around
        if self.collision_check(direction) == True:
            print("Collision")
            return
        if self.moves_left == 0:
            print("No more moves left")
            Map.update()
            return

        elif direction == "UP":                    
                self.internal_row -= 1            
        elif direction == "LEFT":
                self.internal_column -= 1
        elif direction == "RIGHT":
                self.internal_column += 1
        elif direction == "DOWN":
                self.internal_row += 1

        self.moves_left = self.moves_left - 1 
        Map.update()

    def collision_check(self, direction):       
        if direction == "UP":
            if self.internal_row == 0:
                return True
            if len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column][(self.internal_row)-1]) > 1:
                return True
        elif direction == "LEFT":
            if self.internal_column == 0:
                return True
            if len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column-1][(self.internal_row)]) > 1:
                return True
        elif direction == "RIGHT":
            if self.internal_column == MAPSIZE-1:
                return True
            if len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column+1][(self.internal_row)]) > 1:
                return True
        elif direction == "DOWN":
            if self.internal_row == MAPSIZE-1:
                return True
            if len(Map.Grid[self.internal_column][(self.internal_row)+1]) > 1:
                return True

        return False

    def location(self):
        print("Coordinates:" + str(self.internal_column) + ", " + str(self.internal_row))

    def check_inventory(self):
        weight = 0
        for item in self.inventory:
            print(item)
            weight = weight + item.weight
        print(weight)



class Map(object):              #The main class; where the action happens
    global MAPSIZE
    can_move = []
    no_moves = []
    Grid = []

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):     # Creating grid
        Grid.append([])
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            Grid[row].append([])

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):     #Filling grid with grass
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            TempTile = MapTile("Grass", column, row)
            Grid[column][row].append(TempTile)

    for row in range(MAPSIZE):     #Putting some rocks near the top
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            TempTile = MapTile("Rock", column, row)
            if row == 1:
                Grid[column][row].append(TempTile)

    for i in range(10):         #Trees in random places
        random_row = random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1)
        random_column = random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1)
        TempTile = MapTile("Tree", random_column, random_row)
        Grid[random_column][random_row].append(TempTile)

    def generate_hero(self):            #Generate a character and place it randomly
        random_row = random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1)      
        random_column = random.randint(0, MAPSIZE - 1)
        id_number = len(Map.can_move)
        temp_hero = Character(str(id_number), 10, random_column, random_row)
        i = random.randint(0, len(ITEMS)-1)
        temp_hero.inventory.append(ITEMS[i])

        self.Grid[random_column][random_row].append(temp_hero)
        self.can_move.append(temp_hero)
        Map.update()


    def update(self):           #Important function
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):                           #These nested loops go through entire grid 
            for row in range(MAPSIZE):                          #They check if any objects internal coordinates
                for i in range(len(Map.Grid[column][row])):     #disagree with its place on the grid and update it accordingly

                    if Map.Grid[column][row][i].internal_column != column:
                        TempChar = Map.Grid[column][row][i]
                        Map.Grid[column][row].remove(Map.Grid[column][row][i])
                        Map.Grid[int(TempChar.internal_column)][int(TempChar.internal_row)].append(TempChar)

                    elif Map.Grid[column][row][i].internal_row != row:
                        TempChar = Map.Grid[column][row][i]
                        Map.Grid[column][row].remove(Map.Grid[column][row][i])
                        Map.Grid[int(TempChar.internal_column)][int(TempChar.internal_row)].append(TempChar)

        for characterobject in range(0, len(Map.no_moves)-1):    #This moves any characters with moves to the can move list 
            if len(Map.no_moves) > 0:
                if Map.no_moves[characterobject].moves_left > 0:
                    print("character moved from no moves to moves")
                    Map.can_move.append(Map.no_moves[characterobject])
                    Map.no_moves.remove(Map.no_moves[characterobject])

        for characterobject in range(0, len(Map.can_move)-1):
            print(str(characterobject))
            if len(Map.can_move) == 0:
                break
            elif Map.can_move[characterobject].moves_left == 0:     #This moves any characters with 0 moves from the can't move list to the can move list
                print("character moved from moves to no moves")
                Map.no_moves.append(Map.can_move[characterobject])
                Map.can_move.remove(Map.can_move[characterobject])



Map = Map()
Map.generate_hero()

while not DONE:     #Main pygame loop

    for event in pygame.event.get():         #catching events
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            DONE = True       

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column = Pos[0] // (TILEWIDTH + TILEMARGIN)  #Translating the position of the mouse into rows and columns
            row = Pos[1] // (TILEHEIGHT + TILEMARGIN)
            print(str(row) + ", " + str(column))

            for i in range(len(Map.Grid[column][row])):
                print(str(Map.Grid[column][row][i].name))  #print stuff that inhabits that square

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == 97:      # Keypress: a
                print("new turn")
                for characterobject in range(0, len(Map.no_moves)-1):
                    Map.no_moves[characterobject].moves_left = 25
                Map.update()

            elif event.key == 115:    # Keypress: s
                print("boop")
                Map.generate_hero()
                Map.update()

            elif len(Map.can_move) > 0:
                Map.can_move[0].move(KeyLookup[event.key])

            else:
                print("invalid")

    Screen.fill(BLACK)



    for row in range(MAPSIZE):           # Drawing grid
        for column in range(MAPSIZE):
            for i in range(0, len(Map.Grid[column][row])):
                Color = WHITE

                if len(Map.can_move) > 0:   # Creating colored area around character showing his move range
                    if (math.sqrt((Map.can_move[0].internal_column - column)**2 + (Map.can_move[0].internal_row - row)**2)) <= Map.can_move[0].moves_left:
                        Color = MOVECOLOR

                if len(Map.Grid[column][row]) > 1:
                    Color = RED
                if Map.Grid[column][row][i].name == "Tree":
                    Color = GREEN
                if str(Map.Grid[column][row][i].__class__.__name__) == "Character":
                    Color = BROWN



            pygame.draw.rect(Screen, Color, [(TILEMARGIN + TILEWIDTH) * column + TILEMARGIN,
                                             (TILEMARGIN + TILEHEIGHT) * row + TILEMARGIN,
                                             TILEWIDTH,
                                             TILEHEIGHT])

    Clock.tick(30)      
    pygame.display.flip()     


pygame.quit()
```

Play around with it and see what I mean. You can press "s" to add a new character. Notice what happens in the shell when a character can no logner move. You're supposed to be able to press "a" to give characters in the no_moves list more moves, but that doesn't work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn’t iterate over an array you’re mutating, which is causing this problem. Instead:

```
arr = Map.no_moves[:] # copy
for item in arr:
    if item.moves_left == 0:
        Map.no_moves.remove(item)
        Map.can_move.append(item)
```

---

Note that this concept applies to almost *every* language, so it’s good to keep this pattern in your toolbox.